# Can I lock the Apple Watch programatically with WatchKit

Tags: watchkit, watchos-3

I am working on an app to be used in the sea. I'd like to offer the user a button to lock the watch, exactly the same way you can from the native Workout app, but I can't find anything in the API which allows this.

Is it really not possible to lock the watch programatically?

Comment: currently  lock the watch programatically is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, I am creating a UI with no controls and then monitoring the user turning the crown and then showing a different UI.

The user can still press the buttons, which they can't in the activities app, but there are no false touches generated by water.